ERROR: frame_id query param is not defined
I followed the Instructions of the official Discord Documantation Getting started with my First Activity but it doesnt work.
https://discord.com/developers/docs/activities/building-an-activity
When I add this code to the main.js file the Page is blank. When I start the server with just the HTML code it shows the Hello World and everything. In the console of the Developer mode of the page with this code I have to add it throws the error message when it comes to line 8. The error Message is "frame_id query param is not defined". It has to have something to do with the SDK because the DISCORD_CLIENT_ID is set correctly I checked that.
This is the code I have to Add:
// Import the SDK
import { DiscordSDK } from "@discord/embedded-app-sdk";

import "./style.css";
import rocketLogo from '/rocket.png';

// Instantiate the SDK
const discordSdk = new DiscordSDK(import.meta.env.VITE_DISCORD_CLIENT_ID);

setupDiscordSdk().then(() => {
  console.log("Discord SDK is ready");
});

async function setupDiscordSdk() {
  await discordSdk.ready();
}

document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = `
  <div>
    <img src="${rocketLogo}" class="logo" alt="Discord" />
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  </div>
`;

This is the code where the page works:
import './style.css'
import rocketLogo from '/rocket.png'

document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = `
  <div>
    <img src="${rocketLogo}" class="logo" alt="Discord" />
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  </div>
`;

The SDK is installed correctly so this shoud not be the Problem. And it shoud be Imported correctly.
I tried many things like pasting the Client Id directly into the newDiscordSDK Function but this didn't work. I tried to truble shoot and found out that the Problem in in Line 8 but still nocht the Client Id so it has to do with the Discord SDK. Then I tried to install the Discord SDK again. But this didn't do anything to. I also tryed to move on with the Documentation from Discord it still showed a blank Page. Then I tried to do the whole Documentation again this also didn't work.
Any help is appriciated :)

Which line is 8? Look there and you will find the issue. Client id may be set, but could be other params needed.

The guide states that you should REALLY use the cloudflared tunnel, it you do not add it to your URL mappings in the developer portal, the app is displayed as a blank page, and therefore will not work. I had the same problem, but now that I set it up correctly with the cloudflared tunnel, it works :)
